# Install MySQLdb module python2.7

Tags: mysql, python-2.7

I installed `MySQLdb` module for `python2.7` using

```
pip install mysql-python
```

But when I try to access I get the error below. Would appreciate if you can help solve the issue

> root# python 
>   Python 2.7.14 (default, Oct 17 2017, 19:22:55)  [GCC
>   4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-18)] on linux2 Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>
> import MySQLdb Traceback (most recent call last):   File "",
>   line 1, in    File
>   "/home/y/lib/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/**init**.py", line 19, in
>   
>       import _mysql ImportError: libperconaserverclient.so.18: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Answer (score 0):

On Ubuntu it is advised to use the distributions repository. Try installing with the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

To get all the prerequisites for python-mysqldb to install it using pip, run this:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev libmysqlclient-dev
```

Comment: I am on redhat. apt-get does not work
> root# sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
sudo: apt-get: command not found